# Historically first axiomatization of the inner product

Tags: reference-request, math-history, inner-products

When was the dot/scalar/inner (however you want to call it) product historically first abstractly introduced as a mapping that had to fulfill certain axioms ?

Answer (score 23):

According to http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/Abstract_linear_spaces.html, the scalar product was introduced by Grassmann in 1844, in a work that was rejected by other mathematicians for many years. Peano was apparently the first to give a clear  and precise account of Grassmann's ideas in his 1888 book *Geometrical Calculus* (see http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Peano.html)